# What are the good "rich" IDEs for Lisp?

Tags: eclipse, ide, lisp, common-lisp

What are the good "rich" IDEs for Lisp?  To clarify by "rich" I mean it should have a good look-up reference, auto complete, auto inclusion, checking of various sorts, some kind of compilation support, version management, REPL, etc.  I have reviewed some of the previous questions/answers (Such as [What’s a good Common Lisp implementation for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/110390/whats-a-good-common-lisp-implementation-for-windows)) but it really does not get to my need/question.  I am used to Eclipse and have found ([CUSP](http://www.bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/index.html) but activity/support seems light).

Don't hassle me about the phrase "rich" IDE, by saying that emacs or slime is wonderful and that it is and IDE. I have used emacs for years during college, I understand. I am wondering what else is out there (and good) more along the Visual Studio, Netbeans, or Eclipse, type UI and feature set?

Comment: Also, if people recommend something you use or like please take the time to vote up their answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Lispworks](http://www.lispworks.com/).

A friend of mine bought a copy himself to develop Lisp programs in his sparse time. (He is very experienced in Lisp)

Lispworks also has a free [personal edition](http://www.lispworks.com/downloads/index.html).

Comment: However, the personal edition "does limit program size and duration" and the professional version costs 900 USD for academic users!

I would go for CUSP. Even though it's development is not very active, I have not had any issues with it and I've been using it for some time with several versions of Eclipse.

Comment: LispWorks is great, highly recommended.

Comment: Russell: It isn't worth $900USD?

Comment: If no-one will be willing to pay any longer for development tools we soon just will have no choices any more.... Just see what happened to a lot of non-mainstream languages, there are no development tools for it a very sad example is the state of affairs for Objective-C outside the Mac.

Comment: Having learned more personally on the side and talking with people further about Slime I would have refined the question.  For my style and IDE experience Lispworks is it.

Answer (score 6):

Hm, strange seeing you dismiss Emacs+Slime as it covers most (all?) the points you've mentioned and a lot more. Note that Slime != Emacs, at all.

edit: E.g., stuff like CUSP or Lispworks are *not* as rich as Emacs+Slime.

Comment: I am already Slime and Emacs.  This question has an underlying modern IDE style assumption or moving away from shell commands and terminals.

Comment: You're already using Emacs+Slime? Well, this is strange since I don't use a terminal or shell commands at all when doing Lisp and I too use Emacs+Slime. I don't see how the terminal and shell commands is even remotely related to Emacs+Slime. 

Yes, Emacs _can_ run in a terminal, but I tend not to do that unless it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

[CUSP](http://www.bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/cusp.htm)

Comment: the link is dead. [Here is the web archive page](http://web.archive.org/web/20120313113947/http://www.bitfauna.com/projects/cusp/cusp.htm)

Answer (score 2):

I have not actually tried it but [MCLIDE](http://mclide.in-progress.com/) sounds nice.  But I concur with most other: [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) is great.