# How do I get SLIME + Emacs set up?

Tags: emacs, ide, slime

[According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997838/what-are-the-good-rich-ides-for-lisp/2018860#2018860), Emacs + Slime already has much advanced functionality. So how can I get syntax coloring, auto-completion, and perhaps even version control management, set up and running in my copy of Lispbox?

If it's of any help, I have installed Lispbox on Mac OS Lion.

Comment: You didn't describe what documentation you're working off of, what you've done, or what you're seeing that you think you shouldn't be seeing, not to mention what OS and versions of software you are using.  Without any of that how can we help?

Comment: @Ross Well I've searched for autocomplete for slime and emacs on Google, found autocomplete mode, have no idea how to install it. I'm using Mac OS Lion, but I'm new to the Emacs way of editing so I really don't know where to start. All I know is that the other answer says it's possible. So how to make it possible?

Comment: If you want help please update your *question* with *all* of the information I asked for in my first comment.

Comment: @Ross That's impossible. I don't have any documentation on my hands, have done nothing much so far because I simply don't know where to start, and don't see anything because I haven't done anything.

Comment: You have done many things in order to have emacs installed, Slime installed.  You have also only provided your OS version.

Comment: @Ross I only installed Lispbox. That is pretty much all I've done unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting should already be working as soon as you load a lisp file in Emacs, regardless of whether you've got SLIME installed or not. If it's not, try doing `M-x font-lock-mode` and see if that turns it on.

Version control isn't provided by Emacs or SLIME, but Emacs can integrate with pretty much any version control system you care to use. I recommend Mercurial or Git. Emacs should start `vc-mode` automatically when you open a file that is in one of the supported version control systems. The manual includes extensive documentation, do `M-: (info "(emacs)Version Control")` to jump right to it.

Auto-completion is more complicated. There is more than one way to skin this cat, but for Lisp SLIME's default method should be good enough. Use `M-TAB` to complete the symbol at point.